# How to read 2 vectors from a matrix in .dat in Fortran

Tags: matrix, vector, fortran

I want to create a program in Fortran that multiplies vectors from a  .dat file that has the following format:

```
                         x1 y1 z1
                         x2 y2 z2
```

The index 1 and 2 refer to the vector 1 and 2, respectively. First I want do identify the vectors, so far I have

```
  program ex2
          implicit none
          real*8 x
          integer i
          write(6,*) "Insert the vectors from vet_in.dat"
          open (10, file ="vet_in.dat")
          read (10,*) x(i), i=1,3
  end program ex2
```

The line of the read(10,*) was sugested to me, I don't quite get it, I thought fortran identified the ij matrix index. And then I wanted to multiply x1.x2, y1.y2 and z1.z2, maybe the loop and de if could be used. Can you help me to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to declare `x` and also `y` as an array of rank 1 and size 3:

```
real*8 x(3), y(3)
```

And also a scalar variable for the result
    real*8 result

Don't write to unit `6`, but use `*`:

```
write(*,*) "Insert..."
```

but I wouldn't write anything at all.

Now you can read the vectors. If they are stored in rows you can read them in one go

```
read(10,*) x
```

or

```
read(10,*) (x(i), i=1, 3)
```

(read about *implied do* in any textbook).

and then the same for `y`.

Then you can make a scalar product of them:

```
result = dot_product(x, y)
```

(see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/DOT_005fPRODUCT.html)

or

```
result = sum(x*y)
```

or

```
result = 0
do i = 1, 3
  result = result + x(i) * y(i)
end do
```

Note that `real*8` is not legal standard Fortran, just a non-standard extension. You can use `double precision` instead until you learn kinds.